# Конвертирование даты в javascript

Tags: javascript, дата

Есть дата в формате: `Tue, 10 Oct 2017 00:00:00 GMT`. 
Нужно средставми `js` конвертировать её в формат `Tue, 10 Oct 2017`, и в формат `2017-10-10(YYYY-MM-DD)`, как это можно сделать?

Comment: попробуй с помощью объекта date - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @stack-it Это вполне очевидно, но каким методом лучше всего воспользоваться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример реализации:

```js
var timeMs = Date.parse("Tue, 10 Oct 2017 00:00:00 GMT");
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(timeMs);
//для стандартных форматов можно использовать Intl
var options = { weekday: 'short', year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' };
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB',options).format(date));
//Не стандартные форматы дат пишем руками
console.log(date.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Для конвертирования в формат yyyy-MM-dd я использовала такую функцию

```
 function dateToFormat(date) {
            if (date != null) {
                var dd = date.getDate();
                var mm = date.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
                var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
                if (dd < 10) {
                    dd = '0' + dd;
                }
                if (mm < 10) {
                    mm = '0' + mm;
                }
                return yyyy + '-' + mm.toString() + '-' + dd.toString();
            }
            else {
                return '0001-01-01';
            }
```